# Why I can't put the value as {zdsqlBean.thszfas} in jsf?

Tags: jsf

When I put the value as `{zdsqlBean.zdljs}`, I can get the result which I want.

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.zdlj}" style="font-weight:bold" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="zdlj2" value="#{zsjBean.zdlj}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{zdsqlBean.zdljs}" var="bll4"
                   itemLabel="#{bll4.descri}" itemValue="#{bll4.value}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

But when I put the value as `{zdsqlBean.thszfas}`, I can't get the result which I want.

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.zdlj}" style="font-weight:bold" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="zdlj2" value="#{zsjBean.zdlj}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{zdsqlBean.thszfas}" var="bll4"
                   itemLabel="#{bll4.descri}" itemValue="#{bll4.value}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Why? The following is the `zdsqlBean`:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "zdsqlBean")
@SessionScoped

public class ZdsqlBean {

    private List<Zdsql> zdsqls;
    private List<Zdsql> zdljs;
    private List<Zdsql> thszfas;


    public ZdsqlBean(){
        this.genzdljs();
        this.getThszfas();
    }   


    public List<Zdsql> getZdsqls() {
        return zdsqls;
    }

    public List<Zdsql> getThszfas() {

        System.out.println("zdsqls1==");

        return thszfas;
    }

    public List<Zdsql> getZdljs() {
        return zdljs;
    }


    public void genzdljs() {
        try {
            String queryString = "select m from Zdsql m where m.filter = :filter Order by m.id";
            TypedQuery<Zdsql> query = DBDAO.getEntityManager().createQuery(
                    queryString, Zdsql.class);
            query.setParameter("filter", "zdlj");

            System.out.println("zdsqls1==");

            zdljs = query.getResultList();

        } catch (Exception re) {
            DBDAO.log("genzdljs() failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        }
    }


    public void genthszfas() {
        try {

            System.out.println("zdsqls1`1==");

            String queryString = "select m from Zdsql m where m.filter = :filter Order by m.id";
            TypedQuery<Zdsql> query = DBDAO.getEntityManager().createQuery(
                    queryString, Zdsql.class);
            query.setParameter("filter", "thszfas");

            System.out.println("zdsqls12==");

            thszfas = query.getResultList();

        } catch (Exception re) {
            DBDAO.log("genthszfas() failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, follow a JSF tutorial and try to understand the concept of what you're doing. Second, use real understandable names for your classes and variable names instead of those letters that generate confusion for readers.

Comment: Third, pay more attention to code indentation, remove the italics and explain in terms of a developer what does it mean _I can't get the result which I want_

Answer (score 0):

You're not populating your second list.  Your constructor should look like:

```
public ZdsqlBean(){
    this.genzdljs();
    this.genthszfas();  //and not this.getThszfas();
}
```

Luiggi Mendoza is right.  Use understandable names if you want to avoid errors like this!!